# java - get html from ip address

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

I have devices that publish an html page when you connect via their ip address. For example, if I were to go to "192.168.1.104" on my computer, i would see the html page the device publishes. I am trying to scrape this html, but I am getting some errors, specifically a MalformedURLException at the first line of my method. I have posted my method below. I found some code for getting html and tweaked it for my needs. Thanks

```
public String getSbuHtml(String ipToPoll) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
    URL url = new URL("http", ipToPoll, -1, "/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    con.setReadTimeout(1000);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("text/html;\\s+charset=([^\\s]+)\\s*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(con.getContentType());
    String charset = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "ISO-8859-1";
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        buf.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

EDIT: The above code has been changed to reflect constructing a new URL to work properly with an ip. However, when I try and get the contentType from the connection, it is null.

Comment: URL cannot be IP address -  it should be something like  - http://192.168.1.104:8080/app/index.html

Answer (score 2):

A **URL** (Uniform Resource Locator) must have a **resource** to locate (`index.html`) along with the **means of network communication** (`http://`). So an example of valid URL can be

```
http://192.168.1.104:8080/app/index.html
```

Merely `192.168.1.104` doesn't represent a URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `http://` to the front of your String that you pass into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Create your URL as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("http", ipToPoll, -1, "/");
```

And since you're reading a potentially long HTML page I suppose buffering would help here:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset));
String line = null;
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = r.readLine()) !- null) {
    buf.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
return buf.toString();
```

**EDIT**: In response to your **contentType coming null** problem.

Before you inspect any headers like with `getContentType()` or retrieve content with `getInputStream()` you need to *actually* establish a connection with the URL resource by calling

```
URL url = new URL("http", ipToPoll, "/"); // -1 removed; assuming port = 80 always
// check your device html page address; change "/" to "/index.html" if required

URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

// set connection properties
con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
con.setReadTimeout(1000);

// establish connection
con.connect();

// get "content-type" header
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("text/html;\\s+charset=([^\\s]+)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(con.getContentType());
```

When you call `openConnection()` first (it wrongly suggests but) it doesn't establish any connection. It just gives you an instance of `URLConnection` to let you specify connection properties like connection timeout with `setConnecTimeout()`.

If you're finding this hard to understand it may help to know that it's analogous to doing a `new File()` which simply represents a `File` but doesn't create one (assuming it doesn't exist already) unless you go ahead and call `File.createNewFile()` (or pass it to a `FileReader`).

Comment: I am trying to implement this, but when i try to get the contentType from the URLconnection, it is null. I have edited my post above to reflect these changes.